# Change Display property of collection of divs breaks Chrome + Non-linear growth in speed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html, getelementbyid

Let's say I have a large number (> 1000) of DIVs on a page. Each has an id in the format of 'div' + [0-n]

If I then iterate through them and call:

```
document.getElementById('div'+i).style.display = 'none';
```

It works extremely efficiently. With 2.5k+ divs, they all disappear almost immediately.

However, if I then iterate through them and call:

```
document.getElementById('div'+i).style.display = '';
```

Understandably, it's slower. These items need to be redrawn and placed.

In Explorer 9, and Firefox 9, it works perfectly.

In Chrome 15.0.874.121 it slows down horribly. It works fine up to a around 500 divs, and then essentially breaks.

Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Also, does setting display to 'block' one at a time impact performance? Or is the redrawing done once the JS has completed? (I'm guessing this might be the difference between the browsers). If so, how do I change the display property en-mass?

Regards,
Daz.

Comment: You could try hiding their parent until all of them are ready to be drawn.

Comment: @Walkerneo - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried it and it didn't seem to help. At the point in which I show the parent, the page pretty much locks up as before.

Comment: Damn, sorry. I wish I knew more about this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to @FritsvanCampen and @Walkerneo. Their suggestions led me to try the following...

Before hiding each element using:

```
document.getElementById('div'+i).style.display = '';
```

I do as @Walkerneo suggested and hide the parent div. I then do as @FritsvanCampen suggested, and use a setTimeout before doing anything else. The code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('PARENT').style.display = 'none';
setTimeout("showAllTheDivs()",1);
```

Hence, the problem browser (chrome), will no longer try to place the divs one at a time.

This seems like a bug, as it's not apparent in Explorer or Firefox, however, this workaround seems to work. I would be interested to hear whether people think I'd encouter problems with a timeout of 1ms. Seems good enough for now though!

Thanks again to @FritsvanCampen and @Walkerneo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a `setTimeout` to consecutive calls to allow the browser to repaint in between and not lock up the entire window. Do them in batches because `setTimeout` does add a considerable delay: `~10ms` per call.

In general it's impossible to control what a browser does. What works in one browser may not work at all in another. In general pick the most simple solution and pray it will be fixed in a successive version.

This does beg the question. Why do you have so many divs on one page? Couldn't you just put them all in one div and show/hide that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason for the divs is that they are a response from a search query. This collection of results can then be filtered on various criteria. As such, I can't show/hide a single div, as I don't know what the search criteria will be. Imagine something like this: http://www.google.com/hotelfinder/#search;l=london;d=2012-01-25;n=4;r=0;hp=1

Comment: I see, but there is no way that a user will ever browse through 2000 results. Perhaps you can tweak your UI so this is never even a problem?

Comment: Sure, I guess my assumption was that if I can keep it client side it will undoubtedly be faster than going to and from the server. This holds true in all browsers apart from chrome, but clearly google have it working in their hotelfinder...